# webcam is connecting in the flash popup but not getting display in red5recorder video panel

Tags: flash, webcam, red5

I am new to red5recorder. I downloaded red5recorder and put it in the location of linux system /mnt/red5/webapps/root/ and changed the server address from 127.0.0.1 to my ip address in record.as and red5recorder.as files to run my application in laptop for webcam. I included "server=rtmp://my.ip.addrs/red5recorder" in flashVars of the script in the red5recorder.html file.Also i allowed my ip address in flash settings and allowed the webcam to the site. But webcam is not connecting with red5recorder video panel. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

For your server line to work you'll need to fix the app path; from what I read, I assume it looks like this:

```
/mnt/red5/webapps/root/red5recorder
```

Move the app so your path looks like this:

```
/mnt/red5/webapps/red5recorder
```

The "root" is a pseudo app and other apps do not get placed within it.